# semantic-ui: get value of dropdown to send to api

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

I am trying to send the current value of the Search Dropdown to an API. I can't figure out what to send into `urlData.value`. I tried `$(this)` and `$(this).val()` and a number of other options but none worked.

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
    minCharacters: 2,
    apiSettings: {
        cache: false,
        url: `http://localhost/search?text={value}`,
        urlData: {
            value:$(this)
        },
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't have to use `urlData` at all. Just need to specify `{query}` in `url`.

```
url: `http://localhost/search?text={query}`
```